# Ikea Maximera in other cabinet; exact dimensions?

Tags: kitchens

I’d like to use IKEA Maximera drawers a cabinet in my current (non-IKEA) kitchen. Without just buying them and hoping for a fit, I’m wondering how precise my cabinet needs to be to match for it to hope to work.

To be more specific, IKEA has the following data:

```
Width: 36.4 cm
Frame, width: 40.0 cm
Depth: 54.2 cm
Height: 7.8 cm
Frame, depth: 60.0 cm
```

Whereas my cabinet is 39.5cm wide and 59cm deep. Am I out of luck or are the IKEA dimensions slightly conservative?

Comment: While this is technically answerable question, I’m not certain why you would ask it here.  You just need to go to IKEA with your tape measure and measure.  I’m not certain why you would expect the posted measurements to perhaps be “conservative”, measurements are what they are, you can either adapt the piece to work in your situation or you can’t, and I don’t expect you to get an answer to this question with usable information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "frame width" that IKEA is referring to is actually the outer dimension of the IKEA frame / cabinet (Metod in Australia). The cabinets are 18mm thick, leaving an internal width of 364mm.
That is precisely the width of the Maximera drawer.

Since your internal width is 395mm, (31mm wider), you should use a timber strip / moulding of 16mm on either side. 1mm difference won't matter.

I just fitted 80x60 maximera drawers to an 80cm custom cabinet (slightly oversized at 82cm). I used 67x11mm mouldings either side and it's perfect.